# Laravel 5.1 + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I have installed Laravel 5.1 and try to connect with mongoDB. I have donwload [jenssegers/mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) I have follow the instrucction but when I go to my app "localhost/myapp/public" it is a empty page, there is nothing.

I have added the service provider:

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class
```

the alias:

```
'Moloquent' => Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model::class
```

and my config/databese is:

```
'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'myappdb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '12345'),
        'options' =>['db' => 'admin']
    ]
```

Anyone knows that is wrong? :(

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

make .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=****************************

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=DB Name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=******

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Then give `sudo chmod -Rf 0777` storage/ and vendor/ folder

Comment: Thanks! But finally I have used mysql hehe